# getdate() and newid() in sql insert statement

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to get the getdate() and newid() value and insert it into the database.

However, it detects "getdate()" and "newid()" as the value an inserted into the database.

Sql statement:

```
$sql="insert into product_detail_image (item_id,detail_image_name,created_on,created_by,guid) 
                values ('".$item_id."','".$name."',getdate(),'".$this->session->userdata('username')."',NEWID())";
```

Result
This is stored into the database
'4548736020191'  '505b274eb69d4b781eddea0ec2514f8b.jpg'   GetDate()   ''   NEWID()

What I wanted for GetDate() is the value of 2015-12-23 14:45:59.330 and NEWID() is 1B7C352A-F46F-45C7-B2F2-697F8200409E.
How should I go about changing it?

Comment: Your question is unclear. What exactly is it putting into the database, and how is that different from your expectations?

Comment: Please see edited question

Comment: @benylim check below answer as well

Answer (score 0):

Please try placing getdate() and newid() outside of the quote.

Comment: @benylim yes, there is -- the entire query is inside a quoted string.  You should not be building queries with string concatenation -- you need placeholders and prepared statements.  Echo `$sql` and you should see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below code. It will work.

```
 $date = getdate();
 $guid = NEWID();

$data = array(
   'item_id'            => $item_id,
   'detail_image_name'  => $name,
   'created_on'         => $date,
   'created_by'         => $this->session->userdata('username'),
   'guid'               => $guid
);

$this->db->insert('product_detail_image', $data);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
# Instead of getdate use date
# Best for Time Stamp
$date = date('H:i:s dd/mm/YY');

# Make sure session library is Loaded.
$createdBy = $this->session->userdata('username');

# NEWID is not an function in php and Codeigniter
# So i'm removing it from below array.
```

So Final insert array is

```
$data = array(
   'item_id'            => $item_id,
   'detail_image_name'  => $name,
   'created_on'         => $date,
   'created_by'         => $createdBy
);

$this->db->insert('product_detail_image', $data);
```